# SQLite EAV pivoting efficiency

Tags: sql, sqlite, self-join

I have an EAV table `data` in SQLite, with columns `source_id`, `parameter_id`, and `value`. The table has several million rows and I decided on the EAV model because there are several hundred possible parameters.

I have a certain query that I need to get seven different parameter values at the same time from any `source_id` for which all seven exist. For simplicity I will say these are `parameter_id`s 1-7. I use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  source_id, 
  data1.value, 
  data2.value, 
  data3.value, 
  data4.value, 
  data5.value, 
  data6.value, 
  data7.value
FROM 
  data AS data1
  JOIN data AS data2 ON 
    data1.source_id=data2.source_id 
    AND data2.parameter_id=2
  JOIN data AS data3 ON 
    data1.source_id=data3.source_id 
    AND data3.parameter_id=3
  JOIN data AS data4 ON 
    data1.source_id=data4.source_id 
    AND data4.parameter_id=4
  JOIN data AS data5 ON 
    data1.source_id=data5.source_id 
    AND data5.parameter_id=5
  JOIN data AS data6 ON 
    data1.source_id=data6.source_id 
    AND data6.parameter_id=6
  JOIN data AS data7 ON 
    data1.source_id=data7.source_id 
    AND data7.parameter_id=7
WHERE data1.parameter_id=1;
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I thought maybe it was more efficient to do subqueries, like

```
SELECT ...
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      source_id, 
      value
    FROM
      data
    WHERE parameter_id=1
  ) AS data1
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      source_id, 
      value
    FROM
      data
    WHERE parameter_id=2
  ) AS data2 ON
    data1.source_id=data2.source_id
  ...
```

Although that format is longer, perhaps the subqueries would be more efficient because they would eliminate the vast majority of rows before performing the JOINs?

I read the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) for optimization and it said that JOINs are done through nested loops. But then it also said subqueries could be changed to WHERE statements anyway.

Is one of these queries "better" than the other? Is there another way to accomplish this pivot that's better? I'm pretty new to SQL and databases so I am still learning a lot, any help is appreciated. And I guess, as a higher level question, is there a better way to design my database? I figured a relational model was not the way to go because there are just too many parameters for most of my data and I need a lot of dynamic queries.

EDIT: I should note that I have an index on `parameter_id` which helps a lot

Comment: EAV and efficiency are seldom mentioned at the same time — except to use EAV as an illustration of how to ensure that things are inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a plain vanilla pivot.

How about this:

```
WITH
input(source_id,parameter_id,value) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,0.051253445446491
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,0.328549513826147
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,0.006703516934067
UNION ALL SELECT 1,4,0.625361373415217
UNION ALL SELECT 1,5,0.790167507482693
UNION ALL SELECT 1,6,0.595345180947334
UNION ALL SELECT 1,7,0.974001209484413
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,0.698550914647058
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,0.731252062832937
UNION ALL SELECT 2,3,0.697219420224428
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4,0.157373823458329
UNION ALL SELECT 2,5,0.621023152489215
UNION ALL SELECT 2,6,0.18642258644104
UNION ALL SELECT 2,7,0.295151106081903
)
SELECT
  source_id
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 1 THEN value END) AS value1
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 2 THEN value END) AS value2
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 3 THEN value END) AS value3
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 4 THEN value END) AS value4
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 5 THEN value END) AS value5
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 6 THEN value END) AS value6
, SUM(CASE parameter_id WHEN 7 THEN value END) AS value7
FROM input
GROUP BY
  source_id
ORDER BY
  source_id
;
```

The result would be:

```
source_id|value1           |value2           |value3           |value4           |value5           |value6           |value7
        1|0.051253445446491|0.328549513826147|0.006703516934067|0.625361373415217|0.790167507482693|0.595345180947334|0.974001209484413
        2|0.698550914647058|0.731252062832937|0.697219420224428|0.157373823458329|0.621023152489215|0.186422586441040|0.295151106081903
```

happy playing ...

Marco the Sane